# XSL need to add separator on the results

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this code. The output has the results on the same line but without any reparation comma, space or slash. I would like to know how to separate if the results output are two results and more.

```
<xsl:if test="count(entry/fields/field_area/data)">
                    <li id="li_area">
                        <span class="st_label">
                            <xsl:value-of select="entry/fields/field_area/label"/>
                            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                                                        </span>

                        <xsl:value-of select="entry/fields/field_area/data" separator="&#xA;"/>


                    </li>

                    </xsl:if>
```

The output is like this:
Area: americacanada (i would like to be like this:Area: america,canada

Comment: Can you edit a question to show a sample of your XML? Thank you

Comment: Yes i did. The result was the same

Comment: How this work. People will complete a form and then the result will be shown on the details page. User can choose multiple areas.

Answer (score 0):

*Separator* attribute of *value-of* would be useful
if your *select* epression had selected **multiple** tags.

This time it is not the case. You have a **single** field
(*text area*) and its content can have parts (rows) separated
with *newline* characters (this is my assumption, as you didn't
show the source data).

If I am right, you should:

- tokenize the source value, splitting it on *newline* characters,
- join the tokens, usimg ', ' as a separator.

For details see description of *tokenize* and *string-join* XSLT functions.

So this script fragment can look something like below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(tokenize(<your-tag>, '&#xA;'), ', ')"/>
```

I used `<your-tag>` as a placeholder for the source tag.

One more remark: Verify whether chars dividing the content of the text area
are newlines (`&#xA;`). They can also be *carriage return* chars (`&#xD;`).

Comment: I have five specific cities that users can choose by selecting them in the form. They can select one or more. In order to have the result i want i have to tokenize each city adn then use string-join function. The string join function i understand but how i will tokenize the 5 options?

Comment: Please post an example of source XML.